# Draw depth works on WP7 emulator but not device

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xna

I am making a game on a WP7 device using C# and XNA. I have a system where I always want the object the user is touching to be brought to the top, so every time it is touched I add `float.Epsilon` to its draw depth (I have it set so that 0 is the back and 1 is the front).

On the Emulator that all works fine, but when I run it on my device the draw depths seem to be completely random.

I am hoping that anybody knows a way to fix this. I have tried doing a Clean & Rebuild and uninstalling from the device but that is no luck. My call to `spritebatch.Begin` is:

```
spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.FrontToBack, BlendState.AlphaBlend);
```

and to draw I use

```
spriteBatch.Draw(Texture, new Rectangle((int)X, (int)Y, (int)Width, (int)Height), null, Color.White, 0, Vector2.Zero, SpriteEffects.None, mDrawDepth);
```

Where `mDrawDepth` is a float value of the draw depth (likely to be a very small number; a small multiple of `float.Epsilon`.

Any help much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Just a quick heads up, you may find more answers on http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The problem is your use of `float.Epsilon`.** From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.single.epsilon.aspx):

> On ARM systems, the value of the Epsilon constant is too small to be detected, so it equates to zero. You can define an alternative epsilon value that equals 1.175494351E-38 instead.

I expect that the emulator is not running a completely accurate emulation of ARM - which is why it works correctly on the emulator and not the device. (I'm not even sure the emulator is actually running ARM - it may well be x86.)

---

It should be noted that adding epsilon to things and expecting the resulting value to be meaningful is highly risky. The value of `float.Epsilon` is the precision of 32-bit floating point numbers (on x86) **around zero**.

At numbers of greater magnitude than zero, the precision delta becomes larger. There will come a point where adding `float.Epsilon` to a given value will give you *exactly* that value back.

Without getting into a [detailed description](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_precision) of [how floating-point works](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point), I will just point out that a 32-bit float (when considered in base-10) can store 6 (or so) significant digits.

---

Personally I would recommend implementing your own ordering system. I've always found the `layerDepth` stuff in XNA kind of weak.

Perhaps you're drawing these components from a list? Just re-order the list when a component is touched?

Comment: +1 This is very interesting... Just out of curiosity, do you know why this happens? Is the ARM implementation of IEEE different than the one used by Intel?

Comment: I don't know. Interesting question, though.